# Running an existing Contao 4 Website on localhost

Tags: contao

I took over an existing contao project and pulled the files from the server for local development. The issue however is, that the page is automatically redirected to https and I can not find where to configure this.

In the `web` folder I'm running this command: `php -S localhost:8190`

and if I open the link, I get unexpectedly redirected to `https://localhost/`

Anybody knows how to keep the actual localhost url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the front end, this is configured in the respective website root's setting. So log into the back end (no automatic redirect to `https` should happen there, at least not by Contao itself), edit the settings of the website root and set the protocol to `http` (or disable `https`, depending on the Contao version). See also [the Contao manual](https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/layout/site-structure/configure-pages/#url-settings).